# Upload Text and Image with one form, storing path and text in database with PHP

Tags: php, image, forms, text, path

I've been working on this code for the last week and its racking my brain. I've searched on forums high and low and can only find very little on this specific subject.

I want to use a form to upload Text and images. Images get uploaded to directory (upload/), while image path and text is INSERTed INTO database table (upgrade.Testimonials). The index, uploader php, and upload folder all exist at www.mywebsite.com/testimonials

UPON EXECUTING THE FORM I RECEIVE A "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $USERNAME SAVED
Stored in: upload/" BUT NO PHOTO IS UPLOADED AND THE PATH STORED IN DB HAS NO TITLE. BUT ALL OTHER INFORMATION IS SUBMITTED TO DATABASE FINE.

I've opened it the file_upload.php in TextWrangler and it doesn't give me any errors. Hosting with Godaddy.

Other than NY major vulnerability to SQL Injection, 
why am i not able to upload the images!?

Here is what I have so far, please help!

> file_upload.php

```
       <?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$dbhost = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$db_name = 'upgrade';
$tbl_name = 'Testimonials';
$ftp_user = '';
$ftp_pass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$ftp_server = "";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass);


// check connection
if ((!$ftp_conn) || (!$login_result)) {
       echo "FTP connection has failed!";
       echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user";
       exit;
   } else {
       echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user";
 }


$Fname = $_POST['fname'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Content = $_POST['content'];
$filePath="http://www.mywebsite.com/testimonials/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$Type = $_POST['type'];

 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
     echo "Error: NO CHOSEN FILE <br />";
     echo"INSERT TO DATABASE FAILED";
   }
   else
   {
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], __DIR__ . "/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
     echo"SAVED<br>";



$query_image = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (fname, email, content, image,type, submission_date) VALUES ('$Fname','$Email','$Content','$filePath','$Type',curdate())";
if(mysql_query($query_image))
{
echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
else
{
echo 'File name not stored in database';
}
}
}



?>
```

> The Form from INDEX.php

```
<form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/testimonials/file_upload.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td width="250">Name</td>
<td>
<input name="fname" type="text" id="fname" /><br />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="250">Email: (will not be publicized)</td>
<td>
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" /><br />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="250">Client Type</td>
<td id="mainselection">
<select name="type" id="type">
    <option></option>
    <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
    <option value="Business">Business</option>

</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="250">Comments</td>
<td>
<textarea id="content" name="content" rows="10" cols="50" style="border-style:groove;box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 4px #888888;"placeholder="Please describe your experience"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="250">Image</td>
<td>
<input name="image" type="file" id="file">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="250"> </td>
<td>
<input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Add Testimonial">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Is your upload folder writable?  Can you change the permission to 777? But do not use 777 for production i dont remember but i think 666 should be enough for writing

Comment: @engvrdr FileZilla wont let me change permissions, Ill call Godaddy in the morning. Do you guys see anything wrong with the coding?

Comment: @kateobrein i think it's not the best way to do but it should work. You can have a look at gd extension and recreate the image is it windows server you host your code?

Comment: @engvrdr Just got ahold of godaddy and changed the permissions, now i am getting 500 error. If i remove enctype="multipart/form-data" 500 error goes away but i still get the "File not uploaded" selfreport. I am hosted with windows, plesk panel.

Comment: can yoo please check if the path is correct?
Or if you file_upload.php is in testimonials folder, you can use  
`__DIR__."/upload/";`

to get full path

Comment: @engvrdr Check out the edits made to the php in my post above. I now receive a "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $username SAVED Stored in: upload/". But there is no image stored in the upload folder, and the path has no title just the directory prefix. (added enctype back to form)

Answer (score 2):

Solved:
Below is working code to; Upload File/image to ftp directory, store the path in database table, store current date, and text from form ALL FROM ONE FORM.

I searched for weeks online looking for a concise way to submit all this information on one row in the db, simultaneously. Could only piece it together, here it is for you guys.

For beginners: 
1)Create 2 files in your html daw. Index.php and file_upload.php. Index will be where you put your html, the file_upload.php file is where you add the php code. Php files usually start with

The ID row must be set to primary key and INT. The rest should be set to Varchar with a specific amount of characters (your choosing).

4)Create upload folder at same location as index.php and file_upload.php. Be sure and add file permissions to upload folder to prohibit or allow public edits.

5) switch out 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/directory' in my code with your website and page directory.

In the following case, upgrade is the database name, and Testimonials is the table name.

> file_upload.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$dbhost = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$db_name = 'upgrade';
$tbl_name = 'Testimonials';
$ftp_user = '';
$ftp_pass = '';
$ftp_server = "";

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");




$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass);


// check connection
if ((!$ftp_conn) || (!$login_result)) {
       echo "FTP connection has failed!";
       echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user";
       exit;
   } else {
       echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user";
   }


$Fname = $_POST['fname'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Content = $_POST['content'];
$Type = $_POST['type'];
$uploadDir = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/directory/'.'upload/'; 
$fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$_FILES["image"]["name"]))
{
// If file has uploaded successfully, store its name in data base
$query_image = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name(fname,email,content,image,type,submission_date) VALUES ('$Fname','$Email','$Content','$filePath','$Type',curdate())";
if(mysql_query($query_image))
{
echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
}
else
{
echo 'File name not stored in database';
}
}
else{echo 'File not uploaded';}

}





?>
```

> THE FORM

```
<form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/testimonials/file_upload.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td width="250">Name</td>
<td>
<input name="fname" type="text" id="fname" /><br />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="250">Email: (will not be publicized)</td>
<td>
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" /><br />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="250">Client Type</td>
<td id="mainselection">
<select name="type" id="type">
    <option></option>
    <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
    <option value="Business">Business</option>

</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="250">Comments</td>
<td>
<textarea id="content" name="content" rows="10" cols="50" style="border-style:groove;box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 4px #888888;"placeholder="Please describe your experience"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="250">Image</td>
<td>
<input name="image" type="file" id="file">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="250"> </td>
<td>
<input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Add Testimonial">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

thanks to @engvrdr

Answer (score 0):

Did something of the kind:

HTML :

```
 <?php
include '../controllers/session.php';

//get new add space
$querysps="INSERT INTO `advertisements`( `advertname`, `active`) VALUES ('',0);
";

require('../../database.php');
$statement = $db->prepare($querysps);
$statement->execute();
//$dummyadd = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement->closeCursor();

$newspace=$db->lastInsertId();

//echo $newspace;
?>
<?php include 'includes/navigation.php';?>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Dashboard
        <small>Advertisements</small>
      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">View Advertisements</li>
      </ol>



    <ul class="">
        <li><!-- search form -->
        <form action="?" method="get">

  <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
    <?php 
     // echo '<label>Live Search:</label>';
      $search = isset($_POST['get']) ? $_POST['get'] : '';
      echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Adds" onkeyup="showResultfs(this.value)" name="search" value="' .$search .'" /><span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" href="?reset" type="button">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </button>';
      echo ' <a class="btn tdn" href="?reset"><b>Clear</b> </a>';
      echo '<br />';
      //echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />';
     // echo '<label>No JavaScript</label>';
      echo '<br /><br />';
    ?>
  </div>    
</form>
</li>
</ul>

      <?php 

                               if(empty($notifmsg)==true){

                               }else{
                               echo " <div class=\"alert alert-success alert-dismissable\">
                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">X</button>
                                ".$notifmsg."
                               </div>";
                               }

    ?>


    </section>

     <section class="content">

      <div class="row">


        <div class="col-md-12">
          <!-- Custom Tabs -->







          <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Create Add</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <!-- form start -->
            <form action="../controllers/addmaker.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="box-body">
              <input type="hidden" name="addid" value="<?php echo $newspace;?>">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Add Name</label>

                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addname" id="inputEmail3" required placeholder="Add name">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Air To</label>

                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="airto" required id="inputPassword3" placeholder="">
                  </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Add Picture</label>

                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="file" id="file" name="file" required accept="image/jpeg" >
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.box-body -->
              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="clear" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
                <!--  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Create Add</button> -->
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" value="submit" />
              </div>
              <!-- /.box-footer -->
            </form>
          </div>





















          </div>
        <!-- /.col -->


      </div>

    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->


  <?php include 'includes/footer.php'?>




   <script type="text/javascript">
    history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
        history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
    });
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
  function showResultfs(str)
  {
    if (str.length==0)
    {
      document.getElementById("livesearchfs").innerHTML="";
      // document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
      return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{  // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        document.getElementById("livesearchfs").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        // document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
      }
    }
    // xmlhttp.open("GET","db-results.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.open("POST","../controllers/fs-results.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
</script>

<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
<script src="../plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="../plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="../dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<!-- Sparkline -->
<script src="../plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<!-- jvectormap -->
<script src="../plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<!-- SlimScroll 1.3.0 -->
<script src="../plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- ChartJS 1.0.1 -->
<script src="../plugins/chartjs/Chart.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
<script src="../dist/js/pages/dashboard2.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="../dist/js/demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP Script:

```
<?php
include 'session.php';

$addid=$_POST['addid'];
$addname=$_POST['addname'];
$airto=$_POST['airto'];
$newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($airto));


$query="UPDATE `advertisements` SET `advertname`='$addname',`aituntill`='$newDate',`active`=1 WHERE `advertid`=$addid";
echo $query."<br>";


saveadddata($query);
handlepic($addid);











function saveadddata($query){
    require '../../database.php';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
}


function handlepic($addid){
    echo "In pic maker"."<br>";
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])==true)
    {
        echo "If passed"."<br>";
        $userid=$addid;
        $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file extention
        $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file name
        $filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
        $allowed_file_types = array('.doc','.docx','.rtf','.pdf','.jpg','.jpeg');
        $pathholder="../../adds/img/".$userid;
        echo $pathholder."<br>";
        if (in_array($file_ext,$allowed_file_types) && ($filesize < 5000000))
        {

            //$pathholder="Ruerenamed";
            if (!file_exists($pathholder)) {
                mkdir($pathholder, 0777, true);
            }


            //make new directory

            //mkdir("$pathholder");
            // Rename file
            $newfilename = $userid . $file_ext;

            //      if (file_exists("uploads/" . $newfilename))
                //      {
                //          // file already exists error
                //          echo "You have already uploaded this file.";
                //      }
            //      else
                //      {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "$pathholder/" . $newfilename);
            //echo "File ".$pathholder."/".$newfilename." uploaded successfully.";
            $_SESSION['serverFeedback']="Advertisement created! ";
            header("Location: ../pages/index.php");
            //include 'ownerprofile.php';
            //}
        }
        elseif (empty($file_basename))
        {
            $newfilename = $userid.".jpg";
            //$pathholder="Ruerenamed";
            // file selection error

            if (!file_exists($pathholder)) {
                mkdir($pathholder, 0777, true);
            }


            $file = '../../defaultpictures/me.jpg';
            $newfile = $pathholder."/".$newfilename;

            if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
                //  echo "failed to copy". $file."into ". $newfile;
            }else{
                //  echo "copied ".$file ."into ". $newfile;
            }

            //echo "Please select a file to upload.";
            $_SESSION['serverFeedback']="Advertisement created with default! ";
            header("Location: ../pages/index.php");
            //include 'ownerprofile.php';
        }
        elseif ($filesize > 5000000)
        {
            // file size error
            //echo "The file you are trying to upload is too large.";
            $_SESSION['serverFeedback']="Advertisement picture is too large to upload! ";
            header("Location: ../pages/index.php");
            //include 'ownerprofile.php';
        }
        else
        {
            // file type error
            //echo "Only these file typs are allowed for upload: " . implode(', ',$allowed_file_types);
            unlink($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
            $_SESSION['serverFeedback']="Only these file typs are allowed for upload: " . implode(', ',$allowed_file_types);
            header("Location: ../pages/index.php");
            //include 'ownerprofile.php';
        }
    }else {
        echo "If failed"."<br>";

    }
}
?>
```